# ubuntu error when install app E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: python-3.x, linux, spyder, ubuntu-20.04, failed-installation

when i run "sudo apt install spyder" this command or another using sudo apt it through an error in ubuntu 20.04
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

Comment: This is more appropriate on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) -- [E: dpkg was interrupted… run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'](https://askubuntu.com/q/163200/727997)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, just follow what the command says. Try to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a'